# How do you distribute software using wxWidgets?

Tags: wxwidgets

(Using C++) How would software developers make a profitable program to distribute? Would they used pre-compiled binaries within the project directory or something? Just learning wxWidgets and I want to make an application to put on a website.

Answer (score 0):

@pizzadog,

The answer depends on the target platform.

If you are on Windows, you create a binary and use a special software to create a distribution.

If you are on *nix - the answer depends whether you want to allow the end-user to compile the software. If you do - you put the link to the source on the site and create a documentation on how to build it. If you don't - you create a special rules file depending on the *nix distribution you are targeting.

If you are on Mac - you put the application bundle for download and clearly state what is the minimal OSX version the program will run.

HTH.

Comment: Thank you! This answers my question well